# Python- Convert .png images in a folder into a video

Tags: python, python-3.x, mp4, avi

I wanted to build a screen recorder with python. So, I used the Screenshot() function of the pyautogui library. When I run the program, I get individual PNG images in a folder like this-----

```
C:\rec\1.png
C:\rec\2.png
C:\rec\3.png
C:\rec\4.png
C:\rec\5.png
```

And so on. Now I want to convert these PNG images into a video of MP4 or AVI format. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://theailearner.com/2018/10/15/creating-video-from-images-using-opencv-python/).

they use the [opencv](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) library:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

then:

> ```
> import cv2
> import numpy as np
> import glob
>  
> img_array = []
> for filename in glob.glob('C:/rec/*.png'): # (The only change I have made is here to the filepath.)
>     img = cv2.imread(filename)
>     height, width, layers = img.shape
>     size = (width,height)
>     img_array.append(img)
>  
>  
> out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)
>  
> for i in range(len(img_array)):
>     out.write(img_array[i])
> out.release()
> ```